# Pandas: complex filtering with apply

Tags: python, pandas

Lets suppose this dataframe, which I want to filter in such a way I iterate from the last index backwards until I find two consecutive 'a' = 0. Once that happens, the rest of the dataframe (including both zeros) shall be filtered:

```
    a
1   6.5
2   0
3   0
4   4.0
5   0
6   3.2
```

Desired result:

```
    a
4   4.0
5   0
6   3.2
```

My initial idea was ussing `apply` for filtering, and inside the apply function using `shift(1) == 0 & shift(2) == 0`, but based of that I could filter each row individually, but not returning false for the remaining rows after the double zero is found unless I use a global variable or something nasty like that.

Any smart way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that with [`sort_index`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdiaLL8YDLAhWEnnIKHf7HDcQQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html&usg=AFQjCNES3WjtC991p2HW-uhsYdOeOB9Tcg&bvm=bv.114733917,d.bGQ) with `ascending=False`, [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
In [89]: df[(df.sort_index(ascending=False) == 0).cumsum() < 2].dropna()
Out[89]:
     a
4  4.0
5  0.0
6  3.2
```

Step by step:

```
In [99]: df.sort_index(ascending=False)
Out[99]:
     a
6  3.2
5  0.0
4  4.0
3  0.0
2  0.0
1  6.5

In [100]: df.sort_index(ascending=False) == 0
Out[100]:
       a
6  False
5   True
4  False
3   True
2   True
1  False

In [101]: (df.sort_index(ascending=False) == 0).cumsum()
Out[101]:
   a
6  0
5  1
4  1
3  2
2  3
1  3

In [103]: (df.sort_index(ascending=False) == 0).cumsum() < 2
Out[103]:
       a
6   True
5   True
4   True
3  False
2  False
1  False

In [104]: df[(df.sort_index(ascending=False) == 0).cumsum() < 2]
Out[104]:
     a
1  NaN
2  NaN
3  NaN
4  4.0
5  0.0
6  3.2
```

**EDIT**

IIUC you could use something like that using [`pd.rolling_sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_sum.html) and [`first_valid_index`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbr9eBhoHLAhUH1XIKHcrwAeQQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html&usg=AFQjCNGjjh5N7DqpbhQcg_t2EeHCLjj_gA) if your index started from 1:

```
df_sorted = df.sort_index(ascending=False)
df[df_sorted[(pd.rolling_sum((df_sorted==0), window=2) == 2)].first_valid_index()+1:]
```

With the @jezrael example:

```
In [208]: df
Out[208]:
      a
1   6.5
2   0.0
3   0.0
4   7.0
5   0.0
6   0.0
7   0.0
8   4.0
9   0.0
10  0.0
11  3.2
12  5.0

df_sorted = df.sort_index(ascending=False)

In [210]: df[df_sorted[(pd.rolling_sum((df_sorted==0), window=2) == 2)].first_valid_index()+1:]
Out[210]:
      a
11  3.2
12  5.0
```

Comment: I may have explained myself a bit poorly: in this case your result is correct, but I want to detect when 2 consecutive zeros happen, and stop right there leaving also the double zero out. Now, when 2 non consecutive zeros happen, it stops leaving the last zero out. For this particular scenario the result is the same, but if the values where [6, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 0], I expect [6, 0, 5, 0, 4] while your code would give [6, 0, 5]

Comment: @RomanRdgz yeah, sorry for misundertood. Take a look to the editev version.

Comment: @jezrael it'll work only with the indices from 1, if indices from 0 you should add 2 intstead of 1. For your example it works well.

Comment: @jezrael why not? It returns only one element with `index` = 12 and `value` = 5. What should be expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then invert `df` and use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) again:

```
print df
      a
1   6.5
2   0.0
3   0.0
4   7.0
5   0.0
6   0.0
7   0.0
8   4.0
9   0.0
10  0.0
11  3.2
12  5.0

print df[df.groupby((df['a'].diff(1)!=0).astype('int').cumsum()).cumcount()[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]== 0]

      a
11  3.2
12  5.0
```

Explanation:

```
print (df['a'].diff(1) != 0)
1      True
2      True
3     False
4      True
5      True
6     False
7     False
8      True
10     True
11     True
12     True
Name: a, dtype: bool

print  (df['a'].diff(1) != 0).astype('int') 
1     1
2     1
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     0
7     0
8     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

```
print  (df['a'].diff(1) != 0).astype('int') .cumsum()
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     3
5     4
6     4
7     4
8     5
10    6
11    7
12    8
Name: a, dtype: int32

print  df.groupby( (df['a'].diff(1) != 0).astype('int').cumsum() ).cumcount()
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     0
5     0
6     1
7     2
8     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
dtype: int64
```

```
print  df.groupby( (df['a'].diff(1) != 0).astype('int').cumsum() ).cumcount()[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
1     5
2     5
3     5
4     4
5     4
6     4
7     3
8     1
10    1
11    1
11    0
12    0
dtype: int64

print  df.groupby( (df['a'].diff(1) != 0).astype('int').cumsum() ).cumcount()[::-1].cumsum()[::-1] == 0
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
10    False
11    False
11     True
12     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: This indeed works but, is creating auxiliary columns and then dropping them more efficient than using an appli method? What if the 'a' values can also be negative?

Comment: I think it depends of your `df`, but it can be more afficent as `apply`.

Comment: Solution was modified, temporary columns are removed, you can use negative values too.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the df.groupby().cumcount(). If The example has 12 rows and then are grouped, how can the result still has 12 rows? I checked cumcount in documentation and should give the size of each group, and I think this example does not fit that.

Comment: No problem. You can check `print  df.groupby( (df['a'].diff(1) != 0).astype('int').cumsum() ).cumcount()` . It only counts items in `groups`  from `0` to `len(group) - 1`. Please check explanation, second block.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy's [ediff1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html) function is useful here

```
inverted = a[::-1]
index =  (numpy.ediff1d(inverted) == 0).argmax()
a[index:]
```

Comment: Interesting function, but it would dettect any two equal consecutive numbers, not just 2 consecutive zeroes